# In the LD flags of a makefile, is it better to give the dir with platform-specific libs priority over /usr/lib?

Tags: make, libraries

The makefile of my solution (for Raspbian Buster) contains an `LDFLAGS` definition like this:

```
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

…so that the standard libdir is given priority over the platform-specific one. Unfortunately, I ran into some trouble with one of the libs in `/usr/lib`, which was impossible to link against because of an outdated C++ ABI. When I swapped the dirs, however, everything worked fine:

```
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -L/usr/lib
```

Is it generally preferable to state platform-dependent libdirs before the universal `/usr/lib`? Thank you.

**UPDATE:** The corresponding recipe is fairly standard and reads as follows:

```
$(EXEC) : $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $(EXEC) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBRARIES)

$(OBJECTS) : $(SRC)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SRC)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `LDFLAGS` is a last resort helper. If you use it in your makefiles, this is a good method to make your software non-portable.

Better write Makefiles that directly use the needed `ld` command line.

You could e.g. use command lines like:

```
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@ $(LDPATH:%=-L%) $(LIBRARIES)
```

and put the list of search directories for the library search into `LDPATH`.

Note that the pattern matching macro expansions as used for `LDPATH` are not part of the POSIX `make` spec, but this feature has been introduced by SunPro Make in 1986 and copied by many make implementations, e.h. `smake`, `gnu make`. If you have a older `make`, you need to manually use a `-Lpath` entry for each library search dir intim the command line.

Comment: Do you mean something like this:

LD = ld

prog: foo.o bar.o
 $(LD) -o prog foo.o bar.o

Comment: Direct calls to `ld` are rarely used in Makefiles and your example does not contain the use of linker flahs other than -o. Typical linker flags used in this area are `-L` for the link search path ans `-R` for the runtime link path.

Comment: So you'd rather recommend something like this: $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $(EXEC) -L $(LDPATH) $(LIBRARIES), whereas $LDPATH will contain my two libdirs, right?

Comment: Correct, this is what I recommend.

Comment: OK, thx. You could please add this info to your original answer, so that I can accept it.

Comment: ok I added the text to the answer